# WPF how to test if MouseIsOver element during drag and drop operation

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have drag and drop enabled for a listview but I noted that the `UIelement.IsMouseOver` doesn't work during a drag and drop operation.

Source: "This is because WPF blocks all mouse actions when we doing drag drop action. You can use `EventTrigger` with an  animation to do this."

[Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ea591ec9-eac8-42ee-a5d1-396e666ba726/dragover-interference-with-ismouseover-triggered-style?forum=wpf)

However, I am very curious why the drag drop action would block mouse actions. and if that is the case, how should i be testing if the mouse is over an element during a drag and drop operation

```
int GetIndexOfListViewItemMouseIsOver(ListView listview)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < listview.Items.Count; ++i)
  {
    ListViewItem item = listview.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listview.Items[i]) as ListViewItem;
    if (item != null && item.IsMouseOver)
    {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Did you try [Mouse.DirectlyOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.directlyover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the index for inserting your dropped item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method: `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`. You should have the mouse location in the drag/drop event parameters (that I assume exist but are not shown). I'm not sure on the frame of reference needed for the point passed into `HitTest`.